# Gesture Swipe Problems in Flash

Tags: android, flash, adobe, swipe, gesture

I'm planning to make a digital magazine with adobe flash cc 2014. I have different scenes for different page and I use Gesture_SWIPE to navigate the magazine.
The problem is, I only write the script in 1 scene but  it worked for all the scenes. So I can do the swipe in all scenes.
While I want each scenes have a different action such as only page 1 that can't be swiped to the left, only page 2 can be swiped up and down and etc
I did use the if else in each case, it worked for the swiped left, but not working for the swipe right.
Can you please help me? How can I make this scripts work only for 1 scene?

This is my gesture swipe code:

```
import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;  


Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;  


stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, SwipeHandler);  


function SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void  
{  
  switch(event.offsetX)  
  {  
       case 1: //swiped right  
       {  
            prevScene();  
            break;  
            if(this.currentScene.name == "Scene 1") //THIS ONE DIDN'T WORK  
            {  
                 stop();  
            }  

       }  
       case -1: //swiped left  
       {  
            if(this.currentScene.name == "Scene 12") //THIS ONE WORK  
            {  
                 stop();  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 nextScene();  
                 break;  
            }  

       }  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a little trouble understanding your problem and requirements but a few things to continue with:

- your first case should probably work in the same way as the 2nd
- your breaks won't be always fired so will sometimes flow onto the next case the way your statement were setup.

  ```
  Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

  stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, SwipeHandler);

  function SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void {

      switch(event.offsetX) {
          case 1:
              if(this.currentScene.name == "Scene 1") {
                  stop();
              } else {
                  prevScene();
              }
          break;
          case -1:
              if(this.currentScene.name == "Scene 12") {
                  stop();
              } else{
                  nextScene();
              }
              break;
          default:
              //something else happened
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @Vidya-Chandrika did this work for you or did you need something different?